# IOS: property for class not allocated

Tags: ios, class, uiview

I have a UIView that I call "second" inside another UIView called "one".
At "second" I assign a class (class "Home.h" ) in the Inspector identity (Custom class).
The class work fine on "second" view and I have not problem.

My dubt now is how to access at element of Home by external class. If inside Home I set some variables (with properthy and synthesyze) I can't control them from another class because it say me that class Home it's not allocated...how can I solve this situation?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also pretty new to Objective-C and Xcode, but I believe all you have to do is import the header file of the "Home" class (Home.h) to the external class that you want to use it in. In this external class you would have to instantiate an object of the home class. Something that may look like this:

```
/* File: "ExternalClass.h"
* This is the Super-View class of the "Home" class
*/

/* An example using Cocoa rather than Cocoa Touch */
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

// Imports a quick reference to the class without loading the classes methods
@class Home;

@interface ExternalClass : NSView {

/* This creates an object of class "Home" in which a pointer for the "Home" class can be stored
 * From here all you would have to do is import the 'Home.h' file to the 'ExternalClass.m' file
 * and instantiate home objects and call methods of the 'home' class within the 'ExternalClass.m' files methods
 */
Home *homeObject;

}
```

This declares memory for the an object of the "Home" class to be used within the ExternalClass.m... You would then have to assign the homeObject instance variable the class 'aloc' method for the Home class like this:

```
homeObject = [[alloc Home] initWithSomeProperties:var1 andMoreProperties:varEtc];
```

Comment: You may have to init the variable within the ExternalClass.m init method depending on how you are using the object throughout the program.